# Printing line number of identified duplicate word

Tags: python

I've created a program that can correctly identify duplicate words, but I did it in a manner that doesn't allow me to identify the line from which the duplicate comes from. I did create a list of the lines (linelist), which then takes all of the words from those lines and spits them into their own list. I've been searching for a way to show which line the duplicate comes from.

The text that is being run though the program can be found below, followed by the program itself. Ignore the blank line after each quote as that doesn't appear in the input text file. Also, for reference, the "XXX" mark is where I would want the line number to appear.

> He that would make his own liberty liberty secure,
>
> must guard even his enemy from oppression;
>
> for for if he violates this duty, he
>
> he establishes a precedent that will reach to himself.
>
> -- Thomas Paine

```
import math
file = open(str(input("Enter file name: ")), "r")

linelist = []

file_cont = file.readlines()
for lines in file_cont:
    linelist.append(lines)

wordlist = []
# function that splits file into lines, then into words

def split_words(string):
    lines = string
    for line in lines:
        for word in line.split():
            yield word

# loop to add each word from prior function into a single list

for word in split_words(file_cont):
    wordlist.append(word)

# variables declared
x = 0
y = 1
z = len(wordlist)

# loop that prints the first and following word next to each other
while z > x:
    #print(wordlist[x], wordlist[y])

    if wordlist[x] == wordlist[y]:
        print("Found word: ",'"',wordlist[x],'"'," on line {}.".format(XXX), sep="")

    x += 1
    y += 1

    if y == z:
        break
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is `He`  the same as `he`?

Comment: No. The words that it picks up are liberty (duplicate on line 1), for (duplicate on line 2), and he (which appears on line three, but the duplicate is on line 4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looking for duplicates in one long list of words, keep it in a nested `list`.

```
# why import math?

with open(input("Enter file name: "), "r") as f: # input() already returns a str
    linelist = [line.split() for line in f.readlines()] # don't need to duplicate this with file_cont

for l in range(len(linelist)-1): # -1 to avoid index out of range
    for w in range(len(linelist[l])-1): # -1 to avoid index out of range
        if linelist[l][w] == linelist[l][w+1]:
            print("Found word: ",'"',linelist[l][w],'"'," on line {}.".format(l+1), sep="")

    if linelist[l][-1] == linelist[l+1][0]: # check repetition between lines
        print("Found word: ",'"',linelist[l][-1],'"'," on line {}.".format(l+2), sep="")

for w in range(len(linelist[-1])-1): # check last line
    if linelist[-1][w] == linelist[-1][w+1]:
            print("Found word: ",'"',linelist[-1][w],'"'," on line {}.".format(len(linelist)), sep="")
```

File (extra `guard` added to show that only consecutive repeats are checked):

```
He that would make his own liberty liberty secure, 
must guard even his enemy from guard oppression;
for for if he violates this duty, he
he establishes a precedent that will reach to himself.
-- Thomas Paine
```

Result:

```
Found word: "liberty" on line 1.
Found word: "for" on line 3.
Found word: "he" on line 4.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise creating a dictionary where keys are words' indexes and values are current line index.

You can generate it from linelist.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple with enumeration:

```
with open('data.txt') as data:
    lines = [i.split() for i in data]

for i, j in enumerate(lines):
    if any(j[h] == j[h + 1] for h, k in enumerate(j[:-1])):
        print i + 1 # add one because counting starts 0
```

Comment: This just checks whether a word appears twice in a line - I think the goal is to check for double words ("and and", but not "and then and").

Comment: Perhaps, that may be the case. Let me see how I can fix my answer.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Fixed it to do as you said.

Comment: The new version doesn't seem to check for the last word in a line being the same as the first word in the next line.